# MySQL with multiple LIKE options. What's the alternative option?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, sql-like

I am writing a PDO prepare, but I want to know if there is another good way to write it so it runs faster.
Here is the code:

```
function comp_post_code($cat, $comp_post_code){
            global $DBH;
            $STH = $DBH->prepare("SELECT * from uk_data where 
                                    cat10 like :comp_post_code  AND (
                                    cat1 like :cat OR
                                    cat2 like :cat OR
                                    cat3 like :cat OR
                                    cat4 like :cat OR
                                    cat5 like :cat OR
                                    cat6 like :cat OR
                                    cat7 like :cat 

                                    )") ;
            $STH->bindValue(':cat', "%$cat%", PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $STH->bindValue(':comp_post_code', "$comp_post_code%", PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $STH->execute();
            $STH->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
            return $STH;
            $DBH = Null;
            }
```

I want full data from table so I am using Select. * ....Thx

Edited:- cat10 is a postcode, cat 1 to cat7 are categories. I need to search the categories in a given postcode.

Here is the table format:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `uk_data` (
  `slno` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `comp_name` varchar(150) DEFAULT NULL,
  `comp_no` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `comp_street` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `comp_area` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `comp_post_code` varchar(15) DEFAULT NULL,
  `comp_phone` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `comp_phone1` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `cat1` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `cat2` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `cat3` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `cat4` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `cat5` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `cat6` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `cat7` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `cat8` decimal(9,6) DEFAULT NULL,
  `cat9` decimal(9,6) DEFAULT NULL,
  `cat10` varchar(15) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`slno`),
  UNIQUE KEY `Phone` (`comp_phone`),
  KEY `cat10` (`cat10`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=74504 ;
```

The output I am using:

```
$uk_data_radious = comp_post_code($q,$pc_o);
            while (($row = $uk_data_radious->fetch()) !== false) {
            $comp_name[] = $row['comp_name'];
            $comp_phone[] = $row['comp_phone'];
            $comp_phone1[] = $row['comp_phone1'];
            $post_code[] = $row['cat10'];
            $post_code1[] = $row['comp_post_code'];
            $comp_no[] = $row['comp_no'];
            $comp_street[] = $row['comp_street'];
            $comp_area[] = $row['comp_area'];
            $cat1[] =  $row['cat1'];
            $cat2[] =  $row['cat2'];
            $cat3[] =  $row['cat3'];
            $cat4[] =  $row['cat4'];
            $cat5[] =  $row['cat5'];
            $cat6[] =  $row['cat6'];
            $cat7[] =  $row['cat7'];
            $distance_m[] = distance($Latitude[0],$Longitude[0],$row['cat8'],$row['cat9'],"M");
            }
```

Comment: you need to completely redesign your table structure. if you explain what are these numerous cats for, you'll be given with sensible structure and better query

Comment: Do you have a sample typical query?

Comment: @ring0 i have edited question please check

Answer (score 2):

The [Full Text search](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-search.html) works better on long string for searches anywhere inside. But it requires to create a special index, and change the queries (and is not compatible with InnoDB tables).

This is quite some work. But if the *like* queries are really slow, FTI (Full text index) is a fast alternative.

--

Keeping the *like* queries, there is no much you can do - unless of course change the way you organize your data within the columns - i.e. in order to avoid the *like*.

To optimize somehow the *like* queries you could maybe merge all your cats in a single column (i.e. add a new column *catx*), separated with a special char that doesn't occur in your *cats*, like `:`, and do only one "like" (that should speed up a bit). E.g.

```
cat1: alpha
cat2: beta
cat3: gamma
...
```

gives

```
catx is :alpha:beta:gamma:
```

and do the like on catx

```
catx like :cat
```

- to search a specific *cat*, search ":mycat:"
- to search for a part of *cat*, starting with a word, search for ":start" or
- to search for a ending word, search for "end:"

The *like* search algorithm is more efficient on a long string, than running several times on smaller strings. MySQL uses the very efficient [Turbo Boyer-Moore algorithm](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysql-indexes.html) when the search string has more than 3 characters.

But I have to warn you : there are several constraints linked to this strategy

- the special separator char that shouldn't appear within the *cats*
- any update to *cat[1-7]* requires the *catx* adjustment, so if *cats* are likely to change a lot, maybe this isn't a good solution
- this solution works usually for well known data - like identifiers - which format changes rarely

Empirically, I don't think you can expect more than 25% gain with this strategy.

Comment: I'm not the down voter, but my guess would be the DV is because this suggested structure would break first normal form... overloading a single column to contain multiple, even unrelated values can cause headaches down the road.

Comment: It depends on the data structure - this is a suggestion (as there is no miracle as to dramatically improve *like* queries) that needs to be understood before implementation. This last part is up to the OP, as we are not behind the DB and site designs.

Comment: @ring0 i am using MyISAM as u can see in my question .... FULLTEXT index on all categories cat 1 to cat7 ?

Comment: You categories sound pretty big (100 chars) so it may be worth the work. The FTI is fast, but it requires a setup (adjust dictionary for words you don't want etc...). You need to benchmark your *like* queries / searches to motivate such a change - and again, esp. for FTI, a merging of the cats - adding a new col *catx* - would also help (needs to be thought carefully dep. on how you manage the data - do you update the *cats* a lot etc...).

Comment: @MichaelFredrickson After a rethink, I think the DV was deserved. I rebuilt the answer and added some warnings. The merge solution needs *really* to be thought thoroughly, and not everybody has the experience to balance the pros and cons.